# Magento Extension Installation Error

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to Magento. And when i m trying to Install New Extensions using this key: - http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Netz98_ModuleCreator. everything works perfect but after clicking on install button and then to proceed button i am getting the following error..

Checking dependencies of packages
Installing package community/Netz98_ModuleCreator 1.0.0

CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file /var/www/downloader/.cache/community/Netz98_ModuleCreator-1.0.0/moduleCreator/Templates/Blank/app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Tab/Form.php

I tried to solve but couldn't help it.. can anybody have solution for it??? any answer is appreciable..

Comment: Does the file exist and did you already rule out permission issues (is the user running the webserver process allowed to read the file in question)?

Comment: thanks for giving reply.. @Jürgen Thelen.. I saw the path, where Form.php file is not exist... I have give the following command for the permission to the /var/www/downloader  chmod -R 777 downloader

Comment: same problem here, with the ebizsmart magemonkey extension

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436345/4155825

same bug i guess.  I try this and solved my problem.

[quote]

In file downloader\lib\Mage\Archive\Tar.php find method _extractFileHeader().
Then find the code:

```
if (!($header['name'] == '././@LongLink' && $header['type'] == 'L')) {
    $header['name'] = trim($header['name']);
    return $header;
}
```

And replace it with:

```
if (!(trim($header['name']) == '././@LongLink' && $header['type'] == 'L')) {
    $header['name'] = trim($header['name']);
    return $header;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, chmod -R 777 downloader doesn't work.  -R doesn't seem to go all the way down when there are a lot of directories.

I had to go further down and chmod -R 777 /var/www/downloader/.cache/community/Netz98_ModuleCreator-1.0.0/moduleCreator/Templates/Blank/app/code/local/Namespace/Module for it to set the proper permissions on the deeper directories.